# Understanding a memoization decorator as a closure

Tags: python, closures, decorator, memoization, python-decorators

I'm trying to learn about Python decorators, and I'd like to understand in more detail exactly how closure applies, for example in this memoization context:

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(x):                 
        if x not in memo:
            memo[x] = f(x)
        return memo[x]
    return helper   

@memoize  
def fib(n):
    if n in (0,1):
        return n
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

I understand that `memoize` returns functions that are bound to `memo` values in the enclosing scope of `helper`, even when the program flow is no longer in that enclosing scope. So, if `memoize` is called repeatedly it will return a varying sequence of functions depending upon the current values of `memo`. I also understand that `@memoize` is syntactic sugar that causes calls to `fib(n)` to be replaced with calls to `memoize(fib(n))`.

Where I am struggling is how the called value of `n` in `fib(n)` is effectively converted to the `x` in `helper(x)`. Most tutorials on closures don't seem to make this point explicit, or they rather vaguely say that one function ‘closes over’ the other, which just makes it sound like magic. I can see how to use the syntax, but would like to have a better grasp of exactly what is happening here and what objects and data are being passed around as the code executes.

Comment: _"how the called value of n in fib(n) is effectively converted to the x in helper(x)"_? I think you've got that backwards. When somebody calls, for example, `fib(5)`, what's actually being called is `helper(5)`, so `x` is `5`. `helper` then calls (the real) `fib`, i.e. `memo[5] = f(5)`, so now `n` is also `5`. These are normal function calls. There's absolutely no magic involved.

Comment: I've seen the exceptionally good answer discussing decorators at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python/1594484#1594484), but that doesn't seem to address my particular difficulty

Comment: @MichaelMaggs: you misunderstood how decorators work, you may want to re-read that post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've misunderstood what the `@memoize` decorator does. The decorator is not called each time you call `fib`. The decorator is called *just once* per function that is decorated.

The original `fib` function is *replaced* by the `helper()` function, with the original function object available as the `f` closure, together with the `memo` closure:

```
>>> def fib(n):
...     if n in (0,1):
...         return n
...     return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
...
>>> fib
<function fib at 0x1023398c0>
>>> memoize(fib)
<function helper at 0x102339758>
```

This gives the replacement `helper` function *one* closure, and each time you call that `helper()` function the same `memo` dictionary is used to look up already-produced results for the current value of `x`.

You can see this all work in the interpreter:

```
>>> @memoize
... def fib(n):
...     if n in (0,1):
...         return n
...     return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
...
>>> fib
<function helper at 0x10232ae60>
```

Note the function name there! That's `helper`. It has a closure:

```
>>> fib.__closure__
(<cell at 0x10232d9f0: function object at 0x10232ade8>, <cell at 0x10232da98: dict object at 0x102353050>)
```

A function object and a dictionary, those are `f` and `memo`, respectively. Access the cell contents with `.cell_contents`:

```
>>> fib.__closure__[0].cell_contents
<function fib at 0x10232ade8>
>>> fib.__closure__[1].cell_contents
{}
```

That's the original decorated function and the empty dictionary alright. Let's use this function:

```
>>> fib(0)
0
>>> fib(1)
1
>>> fib.__closure__[1].cell_contents
{0: 0, 1: 1}
```

That's the resulting values for `x` set to `0` and `1` being stored in the `memo` dictionary. Next time I call `fib` with either value, the memo is used. New `x` values are calculated and added:

```
>>> fib(2)
1
>>> fib.__closure__[1].cell_contents
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1}
```

You can see how well that works by timing how long a larger number takes to calculate:

```
>>> start = time.clock(); fib(500); print(format(time.clock() - start, '.10f'))
139423224561697880139724382870407283950070256587697307264108962948325571622863290691557658876222521294125L
0.0008390000
>>> start = time.clock(); fib(500); print(format(time.clock() - start, '.10f'))
139423224561697880139724382870407283950070256587697307264108962948325571622863290691557658876222521294125L
0.0000220000

>>> start = time.clock(); fib(500); print(format(time.clock() - start, '.10f'))
139423224561697880139724382870407283950070256587697307264108962948325571622863290691557658876222521294125L
0.0000190000
```

After the first call, looking up the memo is 40 times as fast as all the intermediate results have been memoized:

```
>>> len(fib.__closure__[1].cell_contents)
501
```

Comment: Ah ha!  That makes it extremely clear, thank you. I had indeed thought the decorator was being repeatedly called.